# Como executar função uma vez por visitante após carregamento do site?

Tags: php, javascript

Como fazer para que o JavaScript execute apenas uma vez por visitante (tipo se já estiver registrado no cokkies do navegador, não executar mais).

```
<?php
     $tmp='<script>
     Push.create("Olá Mundo!", {
                      body: "Esta é uma mensagem nova",
                      icon: "images/logo.jpg",
                      timeout: 4000,
                      onClick: function() {
                               window.location="http://www.google.com.br";
                               this.close();
                      }
                  });
            </script>';

            echo $tmp;
?>
```

Comment: cookie gravado por quem? php? javascript?

Comment: javascript mesmo.

Comment: e como vc setou o cookie?

Comment: amigo estou tentando mas não consegui fazer.

Comment: Você está usando PHP, porque não cria e verifica o cookie com PHP. Daí só dá o echo $tmp; se o cookie não existir ou expirou

Comment: Muito obrigado! Resolvido.

Comment: postei uma resposta baseado no comentário, aproveita e leia esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando PHP, porque não cria e verifica o cookie com PHP. Daí só dá o `echo $tmp;` se o cookie não existir ou expirou

```
<?php
$tmp='<script>
    Push.create("Olá Mundo!", {
        body: "Esta é uma mensagem nova",
        icon: "images/logo.jpg",
        timeout: 4000,
        onClick: function() {
            window.location="http://www.google.com.br";
            this.close();
        }
    });
</script>';


$biscoito=$_COOKIE[acessada];

if(empty($biscoito)){

   setcookie( "acessada", "sim", strtotime( '+1 days' ), '/' );  // 24 horas

    echo $tmp;

}
?>
```

[cookies - php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php)

[empty - php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria utilizando o novo localStorage do HTML 5, é muito simples e acredito que todos os browsers modernos já possuam:

```
<script>
// escrevendo
localStorage.setItem("ja_acessou", "Sim");
</script>

<script>
// Lendo
if (localStorage.ja_acessou) console.log('já acessou!');
</script>
```

Exemplo quantidade de acessos:

```
<script>
if (localStorage.qt_acessos) localStorage.qt_acessos += 1;
else localStorage.qt_acessos = 1;

</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Mas Alexandre em qual parte desse script impediria um novo acesso? Eu quero mostrar a notificação apenas 1 vez por dia.

Comment: Só precisaria ler if (localStorage.ja_acessou) console.log('já acessou!'); e aí tomar a decisão que precisa (redirecionar etc), Lembrando que qualquer solução que você encontrar pode ser desfeita se o usuário limpar os dados do cache do browser (seja localStorage ou cookie).

Comment: pra controlar se acessou 1 vez por dia, armazene a data do último acesso em localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Eu particularmente gosto de usar **cookies** para este caso, exemplo:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function showUmaVesPorDia() {
    var cooki = getCookie("msgCookie");
    if (cooki != "") {
        // ja existe o cookie msgCookie!
    } else {
           // não existe, vamos guardar!
           $("#mensagem").fadeIn('slow');       
           setCookie("msgCookie", 1, 1);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
        showUmaVesPorDia() ;
});
```

Aqui tens um exemplo a funcionar **http://jsfiddle.net/h55rxehe**